# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

i try to develop object detection API,during implementation occur a error,

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

with detection_graph.as_default():
 with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
   while(True):
     ret,image_np =cap.read()
     image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np,axis=0)
     image_tensor =detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
     boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
     scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
     classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
     num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

     (boxes,scores,classes,num_detections) = sess.run(
             [boxes,scores,classes,num_detections],
             feed_dict={ image_tensor:image_np_expanded})
     vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
             image_np,
             np.squeeze(boxes),
             np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
             np.squeeze(scores),
             category_index,
             use_normalized_coordinates=True,
             line_thickness=8)

     cv2.imshow('image',cv2.resize(image_np,(1280,960)))
     if cv2.waitkey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
         break
         cv2.destroyAllWindows()
         cap.release()
```

Comment: can you post the complete error trace?

Comment: File "C:\Users\Sampath\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 492, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: I don't think that's the *complete* error traceback, and please post it in the question by editing, and create a [mcve].

Comment: the integer argument in that particular is empty. Ensure it has a value before running it @sampathkumara

Comment: @JeruLuke didnt understand

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if the stream is opened properly. You can try it by using the below line.

cap.isOpened()

If above method returns true, it means, there is no problem reading the file. Then, you need to set which frame you want to read using below line.

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,frameNumber)

You can simply set the frameNumber to 1000 (in millisec) in case of a live stream!